# Is there a way for dynamical expand of parameter?

Tags: python, parameters, push

in python I have

```
title0="Blabla0"
title1="Blabla1"
title2="Blala2"
title3="Blabla3"
```

etc.

to write them all into a txt.file I'm specifying the path and name of file at the beginning with:

```
fileWrite=open('/.../final.txt','w')
```

and I'm calling the function

```
def FileWrt(typo):
fileWrite.write(typo)
```

after each 'title', to push the information into the file.
So, my question is: Is there a way not to call FileWrt function after every 'title' or can I get rid of repeating FileWrt(title1) etc., after every title?

if I write:

```
FileWrt(descr,title0,title1,title2, etc.)
```

at the end, can I make my FileWrt() function accept as much parameters, as sent, without specifying them every time? Otherwise it will say me that that function takes 1 argument, but n is given.

Thanks

Comment: `title0`, `title1`, ... is a common programming mistake. If you have multiple of a given item, use a data structure to contain them - here a list `titles = ["Blabla0", "Blabla1", ...]` would be appropriate.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but you can have a variable number of arguments to a method / function using `*args`, the `*` being the important part. The result will inside the method/func it is considered a `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will do what you want:

```
def FileWrt(*typos):
    for typo in typos:
        fileWrite.write(typo)
```

The `*` before `typos` means *make a list of given arguments.*

Answer (score -1):

That's how you can write a function with a flexible signature.

```
def FileWrt(*args, **kw):
    # args is a tuple of all arg
    # kw is a dict with all named parameters
    print args, kw

In [10]: FileWrt(1, 2, 3, a = 4, b = 5)
(1, 2, 3) {'a': 4, 'b': 5}
```

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo: This question is a duplicate, so I don't think it serves anyone much to get upset about repeating answers. Anyone who knows about the `*args` syntax could provide the same answer, without intending to copy anyone else.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Please relax, there is only one solution for multiple arguments, I was writing it at the same time and I posted it. Besides: your `typos` is a tuple, not a list.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo And yes, I added keyword arguments, because that is the next question that might pop into the OPs mind.